# Pandas how to get top n group by flag column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,2,1,3,3,1,4,4,1,4], 'match': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})

   group  match
0      1      1
1      2      1
2      1      1
3      3      1
4      3      1
5      1      1
6      4      1
7      4      1
8      1      1
9      4      1
```

I want to get top n group like below (n=3).

```
   group  match
0      1      1
1      1      1
2      1      1
3      1      1
4      4      1
5      4      1
6      4      1
7      3      1
8      3      1
```

My data, in actually, each row have another information to use, so only sort to num of match, and extract top n.

How to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear and what is the top n group here?

Comment: count amount of match in group like 'group, count' , group1:4times, group4:3times, group3:2times, groip2:1times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need if need top3 groups per column `match` - use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) for top3 per groups and then convert index to DataFrame by [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
s = df.groupby('match')['group'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(3).swaplevel()

df = s.index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).merge(df)
print (df)
   group  match
0      1      1
1      1      1
2      1      1
3      1      1
4      4      1
5      4      1
6      4      1
7      3      1
8      3      1
```

Or if need filter only values if `match` is `1` use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.loc[df['match'] == 1, 'group'].value_counts().head(3)

df = s.index.to_frame(name='group').merge(df)
print (df)
   group  match
0      1      1
1      1      1
2      1      1
3      1      1
4      4      1
5      4      1
6      4      1
7      3      1
8      3      1
```

Solution with `isin` and ordered categoricals:

```
#if need filter match == 1
idx = df.loc[df['match'] == 1, 'group'].value_counts().head(3).index
#if dont need filter
#idx = df.group.value_counts().head(3).index
df = df[df.group.isin(idx)]

df['group'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['group'], ordered=True, categories=idx)

df = df.sort_values('group')
print (df)
  group  match
0     1      1
2     1      1
5     1      1
8     1      1
6     4      1
7     4      1
9     4      1
3     3      1
4     3      1
```

Difference in solutions is best seen in changed data of `match` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,2,1,3,3,1,4,4,1,4,10,20,10,20,10,30,40], 
                   'match': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

print (df)
    group  match
0       1      1
1       2      1
2       1      1
3       3      1
4       3      1
5       1      1
6       4      1
7       4      1
8       1      1
9       4      1
10     10      0
11     20      0
12     10      0
13     20      0
14     10      0
15     30      0
16     40      0
```

Top3 values per groups by match:

```
s = df.groupby('match')['group'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(3).swaplevel()
df1 = s.index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).merge(df)
print (df1)
    group  match
0      10      0
1      10      0
2      10      0
3      20      0
4      20      0
5      30      0
6       1      1
7       1      1
8       1      1
9       1      1
10      4      1
11      4      1
12      4      1
13      3      1
14      3      1
```

Top3 values by match == 1:

```
s = df.loc[df['match'] == 1, 'group'].value_counts().head(3)

df2 = s.index.to_frame(name='group').merge(df)
print (df2)
   group  match
0      1      1
1      1      1
2      1      1
3      1      1
4      4      1
5      4      1
6      4      1
7      3      1
8      3      1
```

Top3 values, `match` column is not important:

```
s = df['group'].value_counts().head(3)
df3 = s.index.to_frame(name='group').merge(df)
print (df3)
   group  match
0      1      1
1      1      1
2      1      1
3      1      1
4     10      0
5     10      0
6     10      0
7      4      1
8      4      1
9      4      1
```

Comment: @anky_91 - hmmm, I think yes, because if Multiindex there is problem match both levels

Comment: thanks, your first solution works! but second solution raise TypeError: to_frame() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: sorry, perhaps my pandas is old. (0.23.4)

Comment: @rootpetit - yes, you are right, need `s.index.rename_axis('group').to_frame()` instead `s.index.to_frame(name='group')`

Comment: or `pd.DataFrame({'group': s.index})`

Comment: @rootpetit - I add solution with changed data for see difference in solutions.

Comment: thank you useful answer. In my case,  ` pd.DataFrame({'group': s.index}).merge(df) ` works well. I see another way and link you suggest.